# Linking and Redirecting between multiple applications running under a single system folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am running multiple applications with a single Codeigniter `system/` folder using the recommended way on the Codeigniter wiki. Each application runs fine and I can link between apps using absolute URLs.

Is there some way I can use or extend the URL helper class (functions like `anchor()`, `redirect()`... etc.) to generate links to controllers across applications. I would like to avoid absolute URLs

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Matchbox](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Matchbox/) or [Modular separation](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Separation/) and creat multiple modules. Then you can add controllers, models etc in each module.

Comment: Thanks!! Definitely worth trying

Comment: I looked at it and would like to use Modular Separation - Is there some documentation out there apart from the single page on the wiki you have linked above?